# My loop is executing more times then expected

Tags: c, file, loops

Hi I wrote a function that inputs a string from a file and then prints out the answer, now my loop is executing more then the file has lines:
this is my code :

```
    void CalculateAll()
{
    char str[SIZE];
    int ans;

    FILE* p = fopen("Expressions.txt", "r");
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("FAIL");
        return;
    }
    while (!feof(p))
    {
        int i = 0;
        fgets(str, SIZE - 1, p);
        while (str[i] != '\n')i++;
        str[i] = 0;

        ans = CalculateExpression(str);
        printf("%d\n", ans);
    }


}
```

the file has

```
121 + 34 =
562 + 45 =
100 / 10 =
```

the output should be

```
155 
607 
10
```

but instead I get :

```
155
607 
10
10
```

and my loop is running again even tho I reached the end of the file, does anyone have an idea?
EDIT: its not the same question..

When I changed my code to this my first line is gone :

```
void CalculateAll()
{
    char str[SIZE];
    int ans;

    FILE* p = fopen("Expressions.txt", "r");
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("FAIL");
        return;
    }
    while ((fgets(str, SIZE - 1, p)))
    {

        int i = 0;
        fgets(str, SIZE - 1, p);
        while (str[i] != '\n')i++;
        str[i] = 0;

        ans = CalculateExpression(str);
        printf("%d\n", ans);
    }


}
```

Comment: possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: where do you check the null character '\0' ? If your last line doesn't contain a '\n' the while loop goes over..

Comment: ok so its wrong to use, but how do I use that with fgets?

Comment: @Roberto Trani I read from a file, I made a function that knows how to decipher the string, the problem is its doing 1 more loop then needed.

Comment: Why does code not check the return value of `fgets()`?

Comment: @chux how exactly? while(fgets()!=EOF)?

Comment: Who or what text suggested `while (fgets()!=EOF)`?

Comment: then how do you check the value of fgets ? because its a pointer , and impossible to check like the duplicated question you suggested.

Comment: Something like `if (!fgets()) break;`

Comment: But actually `while (fgets()) { ... }` would indeed probably be better, see the currently 4th answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: @Ove actualy no, now my first line is gone

Comment: if I do while(fgets()) my first line is gone, instead of the extra one.

Comment: Maybe your rewrite isn't right and you're making two loops instead of the one you should? Show your revised code if you're still having issues.

Comment: @Ove I edited the post and added the rewritten code.

Comment: ohh I see the issue. I did 2 fgets.. thats why... stupid me